# List Error "The View {GUID} from List [X] is ill formatted"

Tags: powershell, list-view, custom-list

I ran into an issue with one of my sharepoint lists where any time a user tries to create or modify a view, or view the list settings they get the usual "Something went wrong" error. I finally tracked down the error in the logs and found an error stating:

`"The view {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} from list Lists/MyList is ill formated. Please remove it"`

Problem is, when I look up the view in PowerShell, it doesn't seem to exist. Short of going directly into the SharePoint database and deleting the row, how do I go about fixing this issue?

P.S. I know a similar question exists but there are no solutions and no comments.

Comment: Minor update. After talking with the user I think I've found the view in question that is causing the problem. But the issue still remains that it doesn't seem to exist except on the views dropdown on the list page. The name of the view is there but when I try to delete using PowerShell to look it up by its name and get the ID from there, the error I get back is `Cannot convert null to type "System.Guid".`. It looks like the name exists, since it's showing up as a choice in the view selection, but there is no GUID associated with it.